# Magento 2 Override third party module block file

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides

I am working a Magento2 project and I have installed a third party module **magefan/module-blog** which is used for manage Blog/post.This module is installed in Magento Vendor folder.

path is **magento/vendor/magefun/module-blog** .

I have a custom requirement and some changes/updated in block files.Since module is exist in Magento vendor folder so we can't directly changed in this module.Hence we require to override file

> /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magefan/module-blog/Block/Category/view.php

in

> /var/www/html/magento2/app/code

folder.I don't have idea how to override particular that file.

if anyone know about it.Please help me.

Comment: have you create any module for override this file?

Comment: Create a new module and then use preference or Plugin to override it.

Comment: Follow this inststruction 
https://magenticians.com/magento-2-override-block/

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya,still I have not created any module.Do we require to create module or can do any other way?

Comment: yes you must create module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following step need to follow

**create app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
            \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
            'Vendor_ModuleName',
            __DIR__
        );
```

**create app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0" />
    </config>
```

**create app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="ThirdPartyVendor\ThirdpartyModule\Block\File" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\File"/>
</config>
```

**create app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Block/File.php**

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;
use ThirdPartyVendor\ThirdpartyModule\Block\File as ThirdPartyFile;

class File extends ThirdPartyFile
{
...........
...........
}
```

Run Following Command:

```
 bin/magento setup:di:compile
 bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: The `for` attribute in `preference` tab will not accept `.php` . You should just use `ThirdPartyVendor\ThirdpartyModule\Block\File`

Comment: thanks it was typo  updated answer :)