# Override Third Party Module's Block File in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.3

I Installed Third party module under app/code folder. I created another module under same app/code directory to override the third party module.
I specified

```
<preference for="[Third party Name Space]\Block\File" type="[Name Space]\[My Module]\Block\File" />
```

in di.xml but still I cannot override the Block file of third party module.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: I cant able to override third party module's block file. I followed this answer too https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/210100/63813

Comment: I created custom module and enabled to override that third party module and I specified <preference for="[Third party Name Space]\Block\File" 
               type="[Name Space]\[My Module]\Block\File" /> in di.xml, but still the block file is rendering from third party module instead of from my custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding also depends upon the module sequence. So you can check in app/etc/config.php if your module is after than the 3rd party module or not. And if not then you can add the sequence in your etc/module.xml to load your module after the 3rd party module.
For getting the detail overview of overriding you can check this link
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

Comment: Of course, I added the sequence to depend third party module in my custom module's module.xml, but still the block file is rendering from third party module.